# Parse HTML file with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a short html file loaded as a string in Nodejs.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>NodeJS</title>
    <link href="/style/application.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/script.js"></script>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
  </head>
<body>
<center>
<h1><a href="#"><% title %></a></h1><br>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to get an array of every string between `<%` and `%>`. In this case only title.

Tried some javascript string functions and regex but can't find anything...

Maybe finding all positions of `<%` `%>` and programatically slice the strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really regular expressions could do the trick for you:

```
var str = document.getElementById('template').innerHTML,
    re = /<%\s*(.*?)\s*%>/g,
    matches,
    results = [];

while((matches = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    results.push(matches[1]);
}

console.log(results);
```

​

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/Jwbu5/)**

Comment: worked flawless. I have to get more into RegEx. Lot of potencial

Answer (score 1):

If you call `.split("%")` on the string in question then every odd index in the array that is returned should contain your desired string as long as you don't have any instances of `%` on the page.

Another way to go about doing things would be to first call `string.split("<%")`, and then call `string.split("%>")` on the odd indexes if you do happen to have instances where `%` is an otherwise used character in your page.